# Is there a name for this type of matrix ($C + C^\dagger$ is negative definite)?

Tags: matrices, terminology

Given $C = A + B$, where $A$ is a complex, normal matrix with all negative eigenvalues and $B$ is skew Hermitian, is there an accepted name for $C$?

It has the property that $C + C^\dagger$ is negative definite.

If there's no accepted term for this kind of matrix, can anyone suggest the term they (you) would use for it?

I refer to matrices of this type frequently in a paper I'm authoring and I need a concise term to describe them.

Comment: What key properties do these matrices have? That is, why are they interesting? Intuitively speaking.

Comment: @ajotatxe: They appear in multiple blocks of a particular matrix representation of dynamics in a lossy quantum system. In a sense, they describe how information is lost as time progresses.

Comment: I'm not familiar with dynamic systems, sorry.